# Plone: checkinterval can't import pystone

Tags: performance, python-2.7, plone, gil, plone-4.x

I found [the hint about using checkinterval in the Plone documentation](http://docs.plone.org/manage/deploying/testing_tuning/performance/instancesthreads.html#id3) (for performance tuning) and tried to install it; in my `buildout.cfg`:

```
[buildout]
parts +=
    checkinterval

[checkinterval]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg
eggs =
    jarn.checkinterval
```

However, when I tried to call `bin/checkinterval` after building, it failed:

```
  File ".../eggs/jarn.checkinterval-1.0-py2.7.egg/jarn/checkinterval/checkinterval.py", line 4, in <module>
    from test import pystone
ImportError: cannot import name pystone
```

I had a look in the `jarn.checkinterval` package and found neither a `test` module nor any requirements specification.

I tried to add `test` to the parts list, and `pip install test` and the like; but the `test` package I found doesn't contain the string `pystone`.

So, where can I find this `pystone` utility, and how can I integrate it to have it found?

Or is this `checkinterval` thing outdated anyway?

Comment: For better performance, I would recommend you to use one thread per instance only and to create as many instances as you need; as CPython's memory management is not thread-safe, [Python performance could be worse when using multithreading](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock), so you better leave that task to the Operating System.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pystone should be in your python not your Plone. To check that just find out the python you are using & test the import as below:

```
$ head -2 bin/buildout
#!/home/daniel/dev/Plone/Development/myproject/bin/python

$ /home/daniel/dev/Plone/Development/myproject/bin/python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Jul 15 2013, 18:40:50) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from test import pystone
>>>
```

Will probably fail on your system.

Which platform are you using?  [This fedora user's problem](https://github.com/zopefoundation/zope.testbrowser/issues/5) is similar to yours & is simply solved by `yum install python-test`. Hopefully it's that easy for you?

If you installed Plone using the Universal Installer it should have built you a python that (I think) would have dependencies like this included....

Comment: Thank you - this did the trick! I'm on CentOS, so I was able to use the very same `yum` command.